# QComboBox Delegate и отображение данных в QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, combobox, делегаты

Есть несколько вопросов по коду, и возможно вы предложите более грамотный вариант, т.к мой выглядит как костыль. Буду рад любой помощи.

Вопросы:

1. Как правильно установить значение по умолчанию, что бы оно
   отображалось, возможно минуя метод ***paint()***? Без переопределения метода paint() и без установления значения по умолчанию **text = m_itemValue.at(0);** ничего не отображается, пока не кликнешь по виджету 2 раза, тогда вызовется метод createEditor() и заполнится содержимым.
2. Как сделать что бы значение по умолчанию заданное пользователем можно было установить из вне (по значению **value(Qt::UserRole)**). *Пример: через список инициализации проинициализировать значение и установить в таком то переопределенном методе.*
3. Изначально отображается значение **1**, посредством переопределенного метода paint(), а мне необходимо сделать  **One** , при клике
   появляется выпадающий список в виде текста *One* *Two* *Three*, после окончания
   редактирования отображается снова *1*, *2*, *3*, как сделать так что бы
   по окончанию редактирования тоже отображались *One* *Two* *Three* , а не *1*, *2*, *3*, но при этом метод
   **changeValue(QStandardItem *item)** получал именно числовое значение
   *1*, *2*, *3*. Возможно ли такое сделать?

**Код прилагается:**

***mainwindow.cpp***

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QTableView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QStringList>
#include "delegate.h"
#include <QDebug>

enum Test {One = 1, Two = 2, Three = 3};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QTableView *tableView = new QTableView;
    QStandardItemModel * model = new QStandardItemModel(1,1);
    tableView->setModel(model);


    QStringList itemName;
    itemName << "One" << "Two" << "Three";
    QStringList itemValue;
    itemValue << "1" << "2" << "3";

    Delegate * delegate = new Delegate(itemName, itemValue, this);
    tableView->setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate);

    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(tableView);

    connect(model, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), this, SLOT(changeValue(QStandardItem*)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::changeValue(QStandardItem *item)
{
    qDebug() << "changeValue:" << item->text();
    Test test = static_cast<Test>(item->text().toUInt()); 
    qDebug() << "TEST: " << test; 
}
```

***delegate.h***

```
#ifndef DELEGATE_H
#define DELEGATE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QItemDelegate>
#include <QStringList>

class Delegate : public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Delegate(const QStringList &itemName, const QStringList &itemValue, QObject *parent = NULL);

    QWidget *createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;

private:
    QStringList m_itemName;
    QStringList m_itemValue;
    mutable bool m_isNewValue;
};

#endif // DELEGATE_H
```

***delegate.cpp***

```
#include "delegate.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPalette>

Delegate::Delegate(const QStringList &itemName, const QStringList &itemValue, QObject *parent)
    : QItemDelegate(parent), m_itemName(itemName), m_itemValue(itemValue), m_isNewValue(false)
{
    qDebug() << "CREATE";
}

QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    qDebug() << "createEditor";
    QComboBox *comboBox = new QComboBox(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < m_itemValue.size(); ++i)
    {
        // Добавить элемент (text, value(Qt::UserRole))
        comboBox->addItem(m_itemName.at(i), m_itemValue.at(i));

    }
    return comboBox;
}

void Delegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    qDebug() << "setEditorData";
    QComboBox *edit = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(editor);
    QString currentText = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
    int cbIndex = edit->findText(currentText);
    if (cbIndex >= 0)
        edit->setCurrentIndex(cbIndex);
}

void Delegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    qDebug() << "setModelData";
    QComboBox *edit = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(editor);
    QVariant modelData = edit->itemData(edit->currentIndex(), Qt::UserRole);    // value из Qt::UserRole
    model->setData(index, modelData.toString(), Qt::EditRole);
}

void Delegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}

void Delegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QStyleOptionViewItemV4 opt = option;

    //qDebug() << "INDEX: " << index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();

    // Изначально значение не отображается т.к не сработал еще метод createEditor
    QString text = index.data(Qt::EditRole).toString();
    if (text.isEmpty())
    {
        // Костыль, выборка значения по умолчанию
        text = m_itemValue.at(0);
    }

    static QString oldValue = text;
    if (oldValue != text)
    {
        m_isNewValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        m_isNewValue = false;
    }

    opt.text = text;
    if (m_isNewValue)
    {
        QPalette p;
        p.setColor(QPalette::Text, Qt::green);
        opt.palette = p;
    }

    QApplication::style()->drawControl(QStyle::CE_ItemViewItem, &opt, painter);
}
```

Comment: оформили бы отдельные вопросы, ваши шансы на хороший ответ возросли бы

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Они все по теме делегатов

Comment: Я понимаю, я просто выразил свое мнение...

Answer (score 1):

Показываю пример с комментариями и с надеждой, что он ответит на все ваши вопросы, но если что, я готов (в меру сил и знаний) что-то уточнить и прояснить.

И так, начнем. Тельце конструктора MainWindow:

```
{
    QTableView* tableView = new QTableView;

    // Создаем модель размером 1х1 и внедряем ее в нашу табличку
    QStandartModel* model = new QStandartModel(1, 1);
    tableView->setModel(model);

    // Добавляем хранитель значения в нашу модель, обернутого типом QStandartItem
    QStandartItem* item = new QStandartItem();

    // А вот и наше значение (список элементов для Комбо) инициализированное парами {<value>, <id>}
    QList< QPair<int, QString> > data = { {"Value1", 0}, {"Value2", 1}, {"Value2", 2}}; // О какой же кайф этот список инициализации, сколько ж лет я ждал... Кхм, едем дальше

    // Внимание! Следим за руками
    // Для отображения устанавливаем значение по умолчанию. Первый элемент из нашего списка
    item->setData(data[0].first, Qt::DisplayRole); // DisplayRole - встроенная роль, которая говорит отображению, что связанные с ней данные надо отобразить

    // Сохраним текущий id из списка под ролью Qt::UserRole +1
    // Для чего это нужно будет описано ниже
    item->setData(data[0].second);

    // И наконец наш список значений для Комбо. (см. п.1 в Пояснениях)
    item->setData( QVariant::fromValue(data), Qt::UserRole +2);      

    // Инициализировали нашу обертку нашими значениями. Теперь отправляем это в model
    model->setItem(0, 0, item);

    // Куда пропали аргументы класса делегата вы уже поняли. Если нужны пояснения то п.2
    Delegate* delegate = new Delegate(this);
    tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate);

    //...

    // С вашего разрешения я воспользуюсь лямда-функцией, чтобы все было в одном месте
    // Вы можете оставить ваш коннект (включая функцию-слот) таким как он был
    connect(model, &QStandartItemModel::itemChanged, this, [&](QStandartItem* itm) 
    {
        qDebug() << "Current Item Is Changed. "
                 << " ID = " << item.data(Qt::UserRole +1).toInt() 
                 << " VALUE = " << item.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();
    };

}
```

Пояснения.

1. Для того, чтобы преобразовать в QVariant наш список пар необходимо где-то (рекомендую в каком-нибудь общем заголовочном файле) объявить следующее:

   typedef QList< QPair > MyList; 
   Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(MyList);
2. Объект класса Делегата в шаблоне Model-View-Controller необходим только для формирования способа отображения и редактирования данных, которые должны располагаться в объекте класса модели. В вашем случае данные хранятся в QStandartItemModel, получаются при помощи QModelIndex (это все Model), а оторажаются при помощи QTableView и QComboBox в режиме редатирования данных ячейки (а это View, Controller это все что между ними ) ). Это очень хороший шаблон обработки/хранения/редактирования данных, я рекомендую изучить его работу, тем более, что это совсем не сложно (хотя бы на текущем примере). Шаблон этот используется во множестве фреймворков (особенно в web), так что пригодится.

Мы сформировали данные, сохранили их в моделе, теперь необходимо заняться их отображением. Переходим к классу Delegate. Заголовочный файл полностью:

```
#include <QItemDelegate>

class Delegate: public QItemDelegate
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Delegate(QObject* parent = Q_NULLPTR);

    QWidget* createEditor(QWidget* parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
    void setModelData(QWidget* editor, QAbstractItemModel* model, const QModelIndex& index) const;
    void updateEditorGeometry(QWidget* editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index) const;
}
```

Больше ничего не надо. Теперь реализация:

```
#inlcude "delegate.h"
#include <QComboBox>
// Не забудьте подключить заголовник с MyList, чтобы не дублировать здесь объявление
// typedef QList<QPair<int, QString> > MyList; хотя ... )

Delegate::Delegate(QObject *parent)
    : QItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *Delegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox* comboBox = new QComboBox(parent);

    // Под ролью UserRole +2 мы храним список пар значений
    QVariant vList = index.data(Qt::UserRole +2);
    // Преобразуем Вариант в наш список
    MyList list = vList.value<MyList>();

    // Инициализируем наш Комбо
    for(auto& item: list)
    {
        comboBox->addItem(item.first /*Значение*/, item.second /*ID*/);
    }

    return comboBox;
}

void Delegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QComboBox *edit = qobject_cast<QComboBox *>(editor);

    // Временно блокируем сигналы изменения модели, потому что он эмитируется (emit) 
    // каждый раз, когда в модель вносят какие-либо изменения
    model->blockSignals(true);

    // Сохраняем выбранное значение из Комбо
    model->setData(index, edit->currentText(), Qt::DisplayRole);

    // А теперь нам снова надо внести изменения в модель, 
    // но при этом мы хотим, чтобы соответствующий сигнал (itemChanged) сработал,
    // поэтому вновь включаем сигналы модели
    model->blockSignals(false);

    // Можешь закоментить оба вызова blockSignals и посмотреть что получится

    // Сохраняем в модель выбранный ID
    // В модель внесли изменения и она эмитирует itemChanged
    // В роли Qt::UserRole +1 у нас ID пары
    model->setData(index, edit->itemData(edit->currentIndex()), Qt::UserRole +1);
}

void Delegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &/*index*/) const
{
    editor->setGeometry(option.rect);
}
```

Все. Текста много, но на самом деле все просто.

**Дополнение**

Для того, чтобы изменить цвет текста ячейки (или подложки, или шрифта) в зависимости от каких-либо условий, нам надо использовать QStandartItem, который мы получаем в качестве аргумента сигнала `itemChanged(QStandartItem* item)`.
А именно, как-то так:

```
connect(model, &QStandartItemModel::itemChanged, this, [&](QStandartItem* itm) 
{
    // ID выбранного элемента
    int id = itm->data(Qt::UserRole +1).toInt();

    // Изменение цвета шрифта выбранного элемента
    // Здесь я сравниваю полученный id например с 1
    itm->setForeground(QBrush( id == 1? Qt::darkGreen: Qt::black ));
};
```

В примере я сравниваю полученное значение ID с "жесткой" единицей, но конечно можно где-то ввести переменную (поле класса), задавать ее и сравнивать уже с ней. А чтобы не плодить и не смешивать логику сущностей (так как это у нас все-таки главное окно приложения), я рекомендую наследоваться от класса QStandartItem и сохранять значение по-умолчанию внутри него.

Например так:

```
class MyStandartItem : public QStandartItem
{
public:
    // Установка значения ID по умолчанию
    void setDefaultID(int id) {
        _defID = 
    }

    // Проверяем текущий ID со значением по умолчанию
    void checkID(int id)
    {
        setForeground(QBrush( _defID == id? Qt::darkGreen: Qt::black ));       
    }
private:
    int _defID;
}
```

Это тем более полезно, если ваша таблица будет состоять из множества ячеек.
Тогда наш itemChanged превращается в:

```
connect(model, &QStandartItemModel::itemChanged, this, [&](QStandartItem* itm) 
{
    // ID выбранного элемента
    int id = itm->data(Qt::UserRole +1).toInt();
    static_cast<MyStandartItem*>(itm)->checkID(id);
};
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогаете, а где метод setEditorData() ? Т.к при редактировании элемента comboBox сбрасываться будет на первый элемент, а не на котором он сейчас находится. Еще есть вопрос, как покрасить элемент в другой цвет? Если он отличается от предыдущего значения скажем в зеленый цвет. И чем отличается QItemDelegate от QStyledItemDelegate, когда исп один, а когда другой?

Comment: Насчет изменения цвета не совсем понятно, если значение изменилось то он становится зеленым, а если снова изменилось, то снова зеленым, или красным, или каким, какой критерий? Насчет QStyledItemDelegate просто поменяйте его в наследовании и посмотрите, что получится. В целом его рекомендуют в качестве основного для применения, можно поставить и его.

Comment: Если оно хотя бы раз менялось то текст зеленый. А вообще можно и такой вариант попробовать. Текст зеленый только если значение отличается от предыдущего значения которое было сохранено в нем, если возвратить на прошлое значение в котором был комбобокс, то оно черным обычным цветом.

Comment: То есть, если мы выбираем не изначальное значение (например, любое кроме первого), то зелёный, а если первое, то черный?

Comment: Вот к примеру так: у нас есть 3 элемента (one, two, three), по умолчанию мы задали значение two и оно же отображается(черным - foreground text). Нажимаем на комбобокс выбираем one, после выбора становится текст зеленый(т.к отличается от текущего значения по-умолчанию), снова возвращаемся к two он снова черный(т.к это текущее значение). Выбираем снова one и жмем к примеру кнопку сохранить(вся таблица tableView сохраняется с текущими выбранными значениями), теперь one становится черным и становится значением по умолчанию вместо two. Как то так.

Comment: Понял. До понедельника негде проверить, но мне кажется этот вопрос решается при помощи наследования QComboBox. В наследник при инициализации мы задаём какое из значений является по-умолчанию, ну и соответственно, проводим окрашивание и так далее

Comment: Благодарю вас за обратную связь Александр, если будет возможность скиньте в понедельник ваше решение.

Comment: Не надо наследовать QComboBox, все проще. Смотрите дополнение в ответе

Comment: Здравствуйте еще раз. Только сейчас была возможность проверить ваш код. С изменением цвета все хорошо, работает. Но т.к нет переопределенного метода setEditorData,  при редактировании и изменении элемента выдает код ошибки QComboBox::setProperty: Property “currentText” invalid, read-only or does not exist. Когда этот метод переопределяется, то ошибки нет.

Comment: @Disastricks ладно, я надеюсь хоть немного, но помог. Если еще будут какие-либо вопросы, задавайте. Я сюда еще 14 дней подряд буду заходить до золотой медальки ))

Comment: Используется вызов currentText(), только для получения текстового значения в setModelData, в вашем коде. Нужно смотреть глубже. Я использую qt 4.8.5, так вот, т.к мы не переопределили метод setEditorData, там срабатывает код который проверяет свойства, этот кусок в qt 5 уже удален, поэтому он не выводит текст который я указал выше. Вот здесь можете посмотреть, найдите метод setEditorData https://github.com/stephaneAG/PengPod700/blob/master/QtEsrc/backup_qt/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.8.5/src/gui/itemviews/qitemdelegate.cpp

Comment: @Disastricks а, тогда понятно, у меня Qt 5.12.0