# Qt5 C++ Как сделать так чтобы при выборе QComboBox в QTableView сразу срабатывал сигнал itemChanged?

Tags: c++, qt5

Сделал вставку QComboBox в QTableView по инструкции на [этой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/945156/427903) странице (спасибо Alexander Chernin), но свежие данные из QComboBox в ячейке таблицы по сигналу itemChanged можно получить только после перехода в другую ячейку. Вопрос как сделать чтобы после выбора в QComboBox, сразу был сигнал itemChanged без перехода в другую ячейку и я мог сразу считать из таблицы установленные из QComboBox новые данные? Помогите, мне очень надо.

Comment: Что вы нашли в этом QT?   У меня  впечатления от него такое же, что и в современном мире  ездить на жигулях.  Кто скажет, в чем я не прав?

Comment: @ARHovsepyan вы не правы в ваших впечатлениях

Comment: По теме, просто вызовите присоединенный к сигналу метод. В ответе по ссылке это лямбда, что делает прямой вызов несколько затруднительным, но переделать его на "просто" функцию тривиально.

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что сигнал не срабатывает когда в QComboBox сделан выбор, он срабатывает только после того, как ячейка таблицы потеряет фокус получается, то есть когда будет сделан клик по другой ячейке. А мне как раз таки надо чтобы сигнал срабатывал сразу, как только в QComboBox сделан выбор. Я без примера как это сделать не пойму, только начал изучать программирование на Qt5. И да, у меня вместо лямбда простой сигнал вида connect(model, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), this, SLOT(dialogBoxSelected(QStandardItem*)));

Comment: @ARHovsepyan самому пилить gui труднее, чем юзнуть QT. А альтернатив особо и нет.